# File submit failing with jQuery's Form Data() and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have created a form to upload two files - `questionpaper` and the key. But the Ajax request is not working in an intended manner. I have been trying and trying but unable to figure out the bug. Please help. 
Here is my form.

```
<form name="facform" id="facform" data-abide="ajax" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <fieldset>
  <legend> All fields are required </legend>        
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
      <label> <b> Upload Question Paper </b> </label>
      <input type="file" id="qfile" name="qfile" tabindex="7" required>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns end">
      <label><b> Upload Key </b></label>
      <input type="file"  id="kfile" name="kfile" tabindex="8" required>
    </div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
      <label><img id="loadingimg" src="http://dev.cloudcell.co.uk/bin/loading.gif"/></label>    
      <input id="form-submit" type="submit" class="button tiny" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here goes the javascript part.

```
<script>
//-----------------------//
$('#facform').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {

var fileInput = document.getElementById('facform');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('qfile', file);
formData.append('kfile', file);

    var form_url = 'getfiles.php';

    $("#form-submit").hide();
    $("#loadingimg").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: formdata,  
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){
            $("#loadingimg").hide();   
            $("#facform").hide();
            $("#smsg").html(returnhtml);
            $("#facform")[0].reset();               
        }           

//-----------------------//     
});         
});             

 </script>
```

Comment: Ahh....I solved the problem.. I added $("form#facform").submit(function(event){  
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);$.ajax({
    url: 'getfiles.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
   $("#smsg").html(returndata);
   $("#facform")[0].reset();     
    }
  });   
  return false;
   });
 });

Answer (score 0):

**to upload files using Ajax or `jQuery` , you need to use hidden `iframe`**

this is full example for `ajaxfileupload.js` class allow you to use upload form .

or you could create simple function to submit your form into hidden `iframe` then get the `iframe` body html or text using `jQuery` as response .

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://www.phpletter.com/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phpletter.com/contents/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxFileUpload()
    {
        $.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                //YOUR URL TO RECEIVE THE FILE
                url: 'http://localhost/testing/postfile.php',
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'json',           
                success: function (data, status)
                {
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, status, e)
                {
                    alert(data.error);
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        )
        return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableForm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ajax File Upload</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input"></td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Please select a file and click Upload button</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is ok. But i want to know why my code is not working. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: as i told u bro , you cannot submit files using jQuery , you have to submit your form inside hidden iframe only or using xhr class

Comment: will u be specific with iframe. You mean I have to create a function and add onClick to submit!

Comment: I think this method is also correct. Pl refer http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax